# Open a link in internet explorer windows phone

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, hyperlink, browser

i have this screen:[image: image 1]

When i click the link it is like:[image]

so how can i make it open a new internet explorer browser when i click a link in webBrowser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Subscribe to the WebBrowser's `Navigating` event.
 2) Set the NavigatingEventArgs.Cancel = true
 3) In the event's body create a WebBrowserTask using the NavigatingEventArgs.Uri property.

```
void web_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;

        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.Uri = e.Uri; //Uri of the link clicked
        webBrowserTask.Show();
    }
```